# How many bit strings of length 8 have at least twice as many 0’s as 1’s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bit-strings

A problem on my discrete mathematics homework.

My thought process is as follows:
For there to be at least twice as many 0's as 1's, there can only be at most, 2 1's.

Total possible strings: $2^8 = 256$

Exactly 2 1's $= C(8, 2) = 28$

Exactly 1 1's $= 8$

Does that mean that for there to be at least twice as many 0's as 1's, I would have $8+28$ possible strings, leaving $36$ total?

Comment: What about $00000000$?

Comment: Look at the possibilities before you count. Let $z$ be the number of zeros and $w$ the number of ones. You have $z+n = 8$. How many pairs $(z,n)$ satisfy this and $z \ge 2w$? Now for each of these pairs figure out how many satisfy that condition.

Comment: correct except missing case of 0 1's as pointed out already